# ¿como redirigir de un webform a otro fuera de mi carpeta actual?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Si estoy redirigiendo a una pagina asi:

proyecto/webform2.apx

Pero quiero que me dirija del webform2 fuera de la carpeta proyecto, ¿como le hago?

Comment: En la ruta puedes usar ../ esto te manda fuera de la carpera en la que estas y de ahi puedes usarlas para ir mas atras y buscar el form que quieres

Answer (score 0):

Para devolver una carpeta en la direcciones utiliza dos puntos `..`.
Ejemplo:
Te encuentras en esta pagina:
proyecto/webform2.aspx

Si tienes otra carpeta digamos "Proyecto2" con un `webform` dentro  para redirigirte a esa pagina la url sería:

```
../Proyecto2/webform.aspx
```

Es decir los dos puntos regresan a la carpeta anterior o a la ubicacion padre.
Hay mucha informacion en google sobre esto.